# JSON document failed to index

Tags: json, elasticsearch

i have a json document, which i want to index.

But when i try to index the file, i always get an error.

My json document named file.json---

```
{
  "_index": "myIndex",
  "_type": "myType",
  "_id": "p1486f499782beb828d870f4a92831720e048514f",
  "_score": 14.609365,
  "_source": {
    "content": "When we hear the word summer we think of beaches, sun tans and tiny bikinis. What we ",
    "source": "hello.com",
    "type": "sports",
    "guid": "p1486f499782beb828d870f4a92831720e048514f",
    "language": "en"
  }
}
```

i tried to index the json file like so ---

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myIndex/myType' -d @file.json
```

> {"error":"RemoteTransportException[[Klaatu][inet[/192.168.1.127:9300]][indices:data/write/index]];
>   nested: MapperParsingException[failed to parse, document is empty];
>   ","status":400}

i have also tried like so ----

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @file.json
```

> {"error":"ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive
>   xcontent]","status":400}

How can i index my document, any one knows how to solve this problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure your file.json only contains the `_source` content and not `_index`, `_type`, etc. So in file.json you should only have this:

```
{
    "content": "When we hear the word summer we think of beaches, sun tans and tiny bikinis. What we ",
    "source": "hello.com",
    "type": "sports",
    "guid": "p1486f499782beb828d870f4a92831720e048514f",
    "language": "en"
}
```

Then you can index it like this

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myIndex/myType/p1486f499782beb828d870f4a92831720e048514f' --data-binary @file.json
```

If you want to use the [`_bulk` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) then your file.json need to be slightly different:

```
{"index":{"_index":"myIndex", "_type":"myType", "_id": "p1486f499782beb828d870f4a92831720e048514f"}}
{"content": "When we hear the word summer we think of beaches, sun tans and tiny bikinis. What we ", "source": "hello.com", "type": "sports", "guid": "p1486f499782beb828d870f4a92831720e048514f", "language": "en" }
```

**Note:** make sure to end your file with a newline character. The newline character doesn't appear on the example above.

And then you can send it like this

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @file.json
```

So the bottom line is that when sending the document content via a file, you need to use `--data-binary` instead of `-d`

Comment: @Great:), Thanks a lot Val :), it works just like you have explained :)

Comment: `make sure to end your file with a newline character`. That's the real culprit